# How can I start a login activity form an retrofit2 interceptor

Tags: java, retrofit2

How can I start a login activity inside of a retrofit2 interceptor? Am using dagger2 to inject dependences, is there any best practices? 
say like so- Am getting null pointer on LoginMvp.View mview.

```
private final SharedPreferences preferences;
@Inject LoginMvp.View mview;
private String token;

@Inject
public AuthInterceptor(SharedPreferences preferences) {
    this.preferences = preferences;

}

public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

    Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
    Request request = builder.build();
    Response response = chain.proceed(request);
    if (response.code() == 401) {

         //start login activity
         login();
    }
}

//should call start loginActivity via intent and call finish
public void logout() {
    mview.showLoginScreen();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create static object of application context in Application context as

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static App context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;
    }
}
```

Then register this class in AndroidManifest as `<application android:name="">`
Then in your **mview.showLoginScreen()** method put null check to application context and if it is not null call your login activity as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(App.context, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
App.context.startActivity(intent)
```